# unable to load tag handler class "org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.SubmitTag" for tag "s:submit"

Tags: struts2

i am using Netneans6.8 
if i use "s:submit" its displays error like --- unable to load tag handler class "org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.SubmitTag" for tag "s:submit" 
i have added all necessary jar files.. so what may the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Strut2 tags comes with

> struts2-core-2.0.14.jar

file if you have it then did you added the stuts taglib to your jsp??

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

Comment: yes i added that tag already. but still showing that error.. so what may b the issue?

Comment: yes i added that tag already. but still showing that error.. so what may b the issue? –